# Python: how to find values in a column of a pandas dataframe separated by semicolon?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column of a dataframe `df` like the following:

```
df.a=
0            2
1          2;4
2          4;2
3          2;4
4          4;2
5            1
```

I want to find all the rows that contain the value `4`.
I am looking for a command like

```
df[df.a==4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `str.contains` (as long as the column is a series of strings):

```
a = df.loc[df['a'].str.contains('4')]
```

this returns:

```
   a
0  2;4
1  4;2
2  2;4
3  4;2
```

EDIT: in the general case, you should use a regex expression to match single '4' values:

```
a = df.loc[df['a'].str.contains(r'\b4\b')]
```